# Pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly doesn't send

Tags: python, whatsapp, pyautogui

Two weeks ago, I used the code "pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(phone_number, message,tab_close=True)" to send a WhatsApp message, and it worked fine. However, currently, it only enters the message content into the chat box but doesn't send it. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

I want send massage ok by pywhatkit